# Integrate CKEditor to a blog's razor view Create.cshtml editor-field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, blogs, ckeditor

### For a blog mvc 3 app. I have already the CRUD functionality and for Creating the content of a post I want to use CKEditor. So:

For Create.cshtml View I have

```
  <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>
```

---

Now, CKEditor works fine for simple textarea> elements and a submit button.For example:

```
textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="20">Sample Text</textarea>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

**My question is how to associate it with the model property** in a view so instead of simple multiline textbox it will show CKEditor. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found. A lot cover this . One is http://webcmd.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/rich-text-editing-with-ckeditor-mvc-3-and-the-razor-engine/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, is as simple as this:

```
   <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, new { @class = "ckeditor", rows = "15", columns = "130" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>
```